# Почему не вызывается конструктор?

Tags: c, gcc

Есть динамически подгружаемая библиотека, написанная на C. В эту библиотеку добавлен конструктор (чтобы обойти вызов JNI_Onload). Проблема в том, что конструктор не вызывается. Код очень простой:

```
int flag = 0;

__attribute__((constructor)) 
void before() {
    flag = 1;
}

// Остальной код библиотеки
// Проверка значения флага flag на равенство 1
```

В то же время, практически такой же код для простого исполняемого файла работает.

```
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((constructor)) 
void before() {
    printf("Hello!\n");
}

void main() {
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Согласно](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO.html#INIT-AND-CLEANUP):

> Shared libraries must not be compiled with the gcc arguments `-nostartfiles'' or`-nostdlib''. If those arguments are used, the constructor/destructor routines will not be executed (unless special measures are taken).

Если библиотека подгружает JNI, возможно, там выставлены запрещающие флаги. Кроме того, чтобы конструктор и деструктор отрабатывали правильно в elf-файле должно быть наличие секций .ctor и .dtor. Это можно проверить с помощью команды objdump -h libsomething.so.

Comment: Вы оказались правы, все портила опция -nostdlib.

Answer (score 2):

Рабочий пример.

Это main.c.

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

void main() {
    void *handle = dlopen("./libbefore.so", RTLD_LAZY);

    if (handle)
        dlclose(handle);
}
```

Это before.c.

```
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__ ((constructor))
void before() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

Это сборка и выполнение.

```
$ gcc before.c -shared -Wl,-soname,libbefore.so -o libbefore.so
$ gcc -ldl main.c -o main
$ ./main
```

Это результат.

```
Hello, World!
```

Думаю, нужно смотреть опции сборки. И возможно, JNI чем-то мешает.

Answer (score 0):

Может, это как-то связано с http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202494/why-doesnt-attribute-constructor-work-in-a-static-library?